# Jhipster 6 translation not found issue

Tags: jhipster

i installed jhipster 6 and everything is working fine. but when i generate entities, translations are not available on the frontend though the translation files are there.
on the entity page i get something like : **translation-not-found[blogApp.tag.home.title]**

Comment: When i execute yarn start i get :DONE  Compiled successfully in 18423ms                                                                                                                                        18:23:37

ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/src/main/webapp/app/entities/entry/entry-update.component.ts(10,24):
TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../../../../../Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/node_modules/ng-jhipster/ng-jhipster"' has no exported member 'JhiFileLoadError'.
ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/src/main/webapp/app/entities/entry/entry-update.component.ts(10,59):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to the issue! the generator and the app version were not the same.
when you type jhipster info, you get the version of the generator and when you type jhipster you get the app version.
Both have to be the same. if it's not the same just re-install the generator [ npm i -g generator-jhipster@ ]

Comment: Not sure you found a solution as I don't understand how this is linked with your issue. `jhipster info` is not the right tool to get version it should be `jhipster --version`. When you execute `jhipster` command in a jhipster project directory, it will use the generator from the local node_modules directory of the project not the globally installed one, this allows to run a different version per project.

Comment: anyways i found out that the versions are not the same, and when i reinstalled it worked perfectly!

Comment: Hello, I tried  npm i -g generator-jhipster@ and it did not correct the issue of translation-not-found