# translation-not-found[landing.title] on the title bar in jhipster 6.5.1

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am having this error "translation-not-found[landing.title]" displaying on the title bar of some of the pages in a jhipster application. I checked on stackoverflow for similar issues and I found a solution [Jhipster 6 translation not found issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972116/jhipster-6-translation-not-found-issue) "npm i -g generator-jhipster@" which i have tried, but the error still persists.  .

This is what my landing route looks like

route.ts

```
     export const LANDING: Route = {
     path: 'landing',
     component: LandingComponent,
     data: {
       authorities: [],
     pageTitle: 'landing.title'
      },
     canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
     };
```

And please, my superiors have no intention of upgrading the jhipster version. Thank you for your support. [image]

In the global.json

```
   {
        "title": "Egisexternal",
         "menu": {
       "landing": "Transactions",
       "overview": "Overview",
       "applicants": "Applicants",
     }
    }
```

applicationlanding.json

```
    {
    "applicationlanding": {
    "title": "Application Landing",
     }
    }
```

Comment: OK, so did you provide landing.title property in json translation files?

Comment: thank you for your response. I have asked some devs around me but no one seems to have the right answer to tell me how to identify | locate the json translation files. Can you pls tell me

Comment: Normally, it should be in src/main/webapp/i18n/en/landing.json but it could be also in src/main/webapp/i18n/en/global.json or anywhere if you modified generated code a lot. The i:mportant thing is more the property path (the json structure) rather than the file location

Comment: I made some edits to the question. I noticed some effects when changing the names on the title bar on other ones without issues, but when changing the names of the ones with issues, they don't reflect

Comment: Without your code it's difficult to say. How many langiages does your app support?

Comment: It supports one language.

Comment: Then why using translations? Just remove the pageTitle from your route and hard code the title in your template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237489/discussion-between-joca-and-gael-marziou).